# nextpnr unconstrained error

Tags: yosys

I am trying to build a clock divide chain on an iCE40 UPduino card and have run into a problem with nextpnr.  I've minimized a working / non-working example.  This code works:

```
// constraints file as follows:
//   set_io -nowarn  clkin     20  # board clock
//   set_frequency   clkin     12
//   set_io -nowarn  clkout    21  # clk out to scope
//   set_frequency   clkout    100.6

// Top module is "clks"
module clks(clk12mhz, c);
    input  clk12mhz;
    output clkout;

    clk12to100mhz myclkgen(clk12mhz, clkout);
endmodule

module clk12to100mhz(clkin, clkout);
    input  clkin;
    output clkout;

    SB_PLL40_CORE #(
        .FEEDBACK_PATH("SIMPLE"),
        .PLLOUT_SELECT("GENCLK"),
        .DIVR(4'b0000),        // DIVR =  0
        .DIVF(7'b1000010),    // DIVF = 66
        .DIVQ(3'b011),        // DIVQ =  3
        .FILTER_RANGE(3'b001)    // FILTER_RANGE = 1
    ) uut (
        .RESETB(1'b1),
        .BYPASS(1'b0),
        .REFERENCECLK(clkin),
        .PLLOUTCORE(clkout),
        //.PLLOUTGLOBAL(clkout)
    );
endmodule
```

But changing clkout to scopeclk in the top module gives this error:
"ERROR: IO 'clkout' is unconstrained in PCF."  Here is the failing code:

```
// constraints file as follows:
//   set_io -nowarn  clkin     20  # board clock
//   set_frequency   clkin     12
//   set_io -nowarn  scopeclk  21  # clk out to scope
//   set_frequency   clkout    100.6

// Top module is "clks"
module clks(clk12mhz, scopeclk);
    input  clk12mhz;
    output scopeclk;

    clk12to100mhz myclkgen(clk12mhz, scopeclk);
endmodule

module clk12to100mhz(clkin, clkout);
    input  clkin;
    output clkout;

    SB_PLL40_CORE #(
        .FEEDBACK_PATH("SIMPLE"),
        .PLLOUT_SELECT("GENCLK"),
        .DIVR(4'b0000),        // DIVR =  0
        .DIVF(7'b1000010),    // DIVF = 66
        .DIVQ(3'b011),        // DIVQ =  3
        .FILTER_RANGE(3'b001)    // FILTER_RANGE = 1
    ) uut (
        .RESETB(1'b1),
        .BYPASS(1'b0),
        .REFERENCECLK(clkin),
        .PLLOUTCORE(clkout),
        //.PLLOUTGLOBAL(clkout)
    );
endmodule
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in the second version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to change `clkout` to `scopeclk` in your constraints file:

```
...
//   set_io -nowarn  scopeclk  21  # clk out to scope
//   set_frequency   clkout    100.6 // ### ERROR ###
```